# Upload, compress and save an image into oracle database as blob

Tags: php, oracle, image, compression, blob

I'm new here and this is the first question I'm doing to this community, I'm gonna be as clear as possible, so first of all I explain the issue:

at the company I work for, we use a web system that manages all the expenses made by the consultants, and for every expense they UPLOAD an IMAGE of the receipt (that can be made directly with their phone's camera). This IMAGES are then INSERTED into an ORACLE DB as BLOB FILES.

The issue then is that the amount of files uploaded it's slowing down the system so the aim is to find a way to COMPRESS large images (because quality it's not important, they only need to read the payment info) during the UPLOAD and then SAVE into the DB into a BLOB file.

Long story short I show you the already working code and some method I've tried.. let's find a solution together.

This is the Upload Form: (I've omitted the hidden info which are usefull for the query but that are not important here)

```
<form action="uploadPage.php" method="POST" data-ajax="false" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <br>
        <center><h3>Allega foto</h3></center>
            <input  type="file"     id="uploadfile"     name="lob_upload"       value="" accept="image/*" onchange="controlloAllegato();" />
            <button type="submit"   id="allegaSpese"    name="allegaSpese"      value="submit" onclick="loadFile();" disabled>Inserisci</button>
</form>
```

So after the file gets uploaded the action send it in a Php File which handle the insert into db:

First step, it retrieves the information about the file

```
$tipo = $_FILES['lob_upload']['type'];
$dimensione = $_FILES['lob_upload']['size'];
$name = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$estensione =  strtolower(pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
```

Then it runs the query

```
$lob = oci_new_descriptor($conn, OCI_D_LOB);
    $stmt = oci_parse($conn, "INSERT INTO ALLEGATI_SPESE (NUMRIGA, COMMESSA, RISORSA, DATA, DATA_INS, NOME, ESTENSIONE, TIPO, DIMENSIONE, ALLEGATO) "        
        ."VALUES(:NUM,:COM,:RIS,TO_DATE(:DATA,'DD/MM/YYYY'),DEFAULT,:NOME,:EXT,:TIPO,:DIMENSIONE,empty_blob()) returning allegato into :ALLEGATO");

        oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":NUM", $numriga);
        oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":COM", $commessa);
        oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":RIS", $risorsa);
        oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":DATA", $data);
        oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":NOME", $name);
        oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":EXT", $estensione);
        oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":TIPO", $tipo);
        oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":DIMENSIONE", $dimensione);
        oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":ALLEGATO", $lob, -1, OCI_B_BLOB);
        oci_execute($stmt, OCI_DEFAULT);
```

Finally there is the part where the image is actually being saved into the db, also there is a resize but it isn't affecting the file size.(this resize function it's here for other reasons and I'm aware that it's not affecting the file ;) ) I kinda want to do the same thing but before the file gets saved.

```
    if ($lob->savefile($_FILES['lob_upload']['tmp_name'])) {
        $blob=$lob->load();
        $image = new Imagick();
        $image->readImageBlob($blob);

        $width = $image->getImageWidth();
        $height=$image->getImageHeight();
        $scale=$width/$height;
        $height=1000/$scale;
        $image->resizeImage(1000,$height,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);
        $lob->save($image);
        oci_commit($conn);

    }else{
        // echo "Errore";
    }
    $lob->free();
```

So my final question: is there a way to process/compress the file before it gets saved into the database?
I've already tried to assign this

```
$_FILES['lob_upload']['tmp_name']
```

to a variable in order to then apply some Imagick() compression functions to it but it's not working.

That's all, if there is something not clear just let me know, thanks in advance for your time.

ps: this is an example of what I want to do, eccept that I'm using an Oracle Database and at the moment I can't enable GD Library but only Imagick
http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/reduce%20the%20size%20and%20make%20thumbnail%20of%20any%20image%20before%20uploading%20using%20PHP.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution Found!

Since the image is directly saved into the database, every process on it doesn't affect the actual size of the file.

Hence I wrote a function that takes the image, process and store it into a temporary folder and then I am finally able to save it into the db with a great disk space saving.

For the image processing I've used PHP GD Extension, there are a lot of tutorial on the web so I'm not gonna post my code.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can start by checking if the resizing actually works.
Are the new dimensions the ones you expect?

```
$width = $image->getImageWidth();
$height=$image->getImageHeight();
$scale=$width/$height;
$height=1000/$scale;
$image->resizeImage(1000,$height,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);

$resizedWidth = $image->getImageWidth();
$resizedHeight = $image->getImageHeight();

var_dump($resizedWidth);
var_dump($resizedHeight);
```

Comment: Yes I've already checked and it works, I also tried to use the Imagick Compression function and it affect the image but if I download it from the db (using sql developer) and compare it with the original the disk space that takes it's the same. The guy who wrote this code confirmed me that this is a resize that is acting AFTER the file is saved into the db so it's affecting how the image is viewed but not the rest. What I'm aiming to do is process it BEFORE the $lob->savefile($_FILES['lob_upload']['tmp_name']). Thanks for your response :)

Comment: Have you also checked the field size in oracle where the image content is stored? Also, the resize you're refering to where exactly does it happen?

Comment: The resize function happens here  $image->resizeImage(1000,$height,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1); if I change the first two values it does change into the database view but the size still remain the same, and this happens because the file has already been saved :)

Comment: for the field size, since is taken from an hiddenhtml is fixed so it doesn't change neither